# How to open a program every 10 seconds

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a prank on my friend by creating a VBScript that open Notepad every 10 seconds. I was able to make the script but it open Notepad the first time but after 10 seconds where the script suppose to open it again I get this error:

[image]

My VBS code:

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
i = 0
Do While i = 0
oShell.run "Notepad.exe"
Set oShell = Nothing
WScript.Sleep(10000)
Loop
```

Comment: Find something more useful to focus your attention on

Comment: It could be because you are setting your oShell to 'Nothing'.

Comment: @AdamJeffers What do you mean with that? I'm trying to learn something new and doing a prank isn't that bad.

Comment: @DigitalVeer Thank you so much for your help. Please put this as an answer so I can choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: No problem, @abdel!
Select my answer when you get a chance; Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with learning something new while having a little fun at the same time ;)
Your issue is that you are trying to execute `Notepad.exe` while setting `oShell` to `Nothing`. Just remove that line and everything should be all good.

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
i = 0
Do While i = 0
oShell.run "Notepad.exe"
WScript.Sleep(10000)
Loop
```